# Product not being added to cart even logged as admin

Tags: 7, commerce

Have a drupal commerce site.

When i click on Add to cart button through its product display it says that the product have been added but when i go to /cart the cart is empty.

No php errors, no watchdog logs, no errors in apache log

I empty cache and disable apc and boost but still i cant see product in my cart even logged as admin

I recently update core and modules, and everything went ok or i think so because it went kind of smooth

Have anyone experince something like this?

Comment: Updating core from 7.35 to 7.38 causing some issue when creating a new order(haven't had a closer look yet).  Not sure if both of our issues related.

Comment: I think i update from 7.32 to 7.38, update jquery, inlinetntityform, ds, webform, vbo, smarttrim, views, ctools, feeds, module filter, address field, apc, captcha, commerce discount.. well a lot of modules but only commerce discount gave me problmes when updating database, error was "Cannot rename field_Data_commerce_discount_max_uses to field_deleted_data_175: table field_deleted_data_175 already exists" i unserstand this but if this error is the reason that product not being added to cart... jesus what it is for sure is that right now discounts are broken hehe

Comment: :) I would try to add a product without discount functionality to isolate the issue. However check https://www.drupal.org/node/1003788 it might be related. Quick check would b ehcecking for commerce_*_load() in your custom code base and make sure you are passing entity id proper. otherwise, you get exception, however, if  add to cart is ajax, the n you see nothing